# Assembly Nasm x86_64 Coredump on ErrCode:139

Tags: nasm

The program starts a normal execution, ignores the user input and then hits an segmentation fault. I'm very new to nasm so I don't have a clue on how to solve this issue so therefore I didn't try anything this version is an version with modules and is straight up coded by me.

Console:

```
****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ vim exp2.asm

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ nasm -f elf64 -o test.o exp2.asm

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ ld test.o -o check

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ ./check

What is your name? Hello, Segmentation fault (core dumped)

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ vim exp2.asm

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ nasm -f elf64 -o test.o exp2.asm

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ ld test.o -o check

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ ./check

What is your name? Hello, Segmentation fault (core dumped)

****@****:~/ASM_PRJ$ echo $?

139
```

The source code is:

```
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------Syscals-----------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
std_in equ 0    ; Standard Input (Console)
std_out equ 1   ; Standard Ausgabe (Console)
std_err equ 2   ; 
sys_r equ 0     ; Lesen (Console)
sys_w equ 1     ; Schreiben (Console)
sys_exit equ 60 ; Syscall beenden (Console)
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------

section .data
        text1 db "What is your name? "
        text2 db "Hello, "

section .bss
        name resb 16

section .text
        global _start


;programm beenden 
%macro exit 0 
        mov rax, sys_exit
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
%endmacro

;print line
; PARAM 1 = .data LABEL
%macro pline 1    
        mov rdi, %1
        call %%strlen
        mov rdx, rax
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, %1
        syscall
        ret
        ;strlen --------------------------------------------------
%%strlen:
        push rcx                ; save and clear out counter
        xor rcx, rcx
%%strlen_next:
        cmp [rdi], byte 0       ; null byte yet?
        jz %%strlen_null         ; yes, get out
        inc rcx                 ; char is ok, count it
        inc rdi                 ; move to next char
        jmp %%strlen_next        ; reprocess
%%strlen_null:
        mov rax, rcx            ; rcx = length in rax
        pop rcx                 ; restore rcx
        ret                     ; get out        
%endmacro
; 

; PARAM 1 = .bss LABEL
; PARAM 2 = .bss Reservierte Bytes
%macro rline 2
        mov rax, sys_r
        mov rdi, std_in
        mov rsi, %1
        mov rdx, %2
        syscall
        ret
%endmacro

_start:
        pline text1
        rline name, 16
        pline text2
        pline name
        exit
```

I would be very thankful for additional learning repositories and tips

My OS Spec: Linux **** 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #864-Microsoft Thu Nov 07 15:22:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

-- Solved By Michael --

```
Updated Source:

; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------Syscals-----------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
std_in equ 0    ; Standard Input (Console)
std_out equ 1   ; Standard Ausgabe (Console)
std_err equ 2   ; 
sys_r equ 0     ; Lesen (Console)
sys_w equ 1     ; Schreiben (Console)
sys_exit equ 60 ; Syscall beenden (Console)
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------
; -----------------------------------------

section .data
        text1 db "What is your name? "
        text2 db "Hello, "

section .bss
        name resb 16

section .text
        global _start


;programm beenden 
%macro exit 0 
        mov rax, sys_exit
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
%endmacro

%macro strlen 1
        mov rdi, %1
%%strlen:
        push rcx                ; save and clear out counter
        xor rcx, rcx
%%strlen_next:
        cmp [rdi], byte 0       ; null byte yet?
        jz %%strlen_null         ; yes, get out
        inc rcx                 ; char is ok, count it
        inc rdi                 ; move to next char
        jmp %%strlen_next        ; reprocess
%%strlen_null:
        mov rax, rcx            ; rcx = length in rax
        pop rcx                 ; restore rcx
%endmacro

; print line
; PARAM 1 = .data LABEL
%macro pline 1    
        strlen %1
        mov rdx, rax
        mov rax, sys_w
        mov rdi, std_out
        mov rsi, %1
        syscall        
%endmacro

; 

; PARAM 1 = .bss LABEL
; PARAM 2 = .bss Reservierte Bytes
%macro rline 2
        mov rax, sys_r          ; get syscall
        mov rdi, std_in         ; get input
        mov rsi, %1             ; Label 
        mov rdx, %2             ; Reservierte Bytes
        syscall
%endmacro

_start:
        pline text1
        rline name, 16
        pline text2
        pline name
        exit
```

Still having an issue where Hello gets printed before user input

Comment: Why does the `rline` macro end with a `ret`? Same with the `ret` after the `syscall` inside `pline`.

Comment: That could actualy be the issue here, ill try that out

Comment: Well, you need to have some kind of jump after the `syscall` in `pline` to not fall into `%%strlen`, but it shouldn't be a `ret`. But I don't see the point of `strlen` being part of `pline`. Just make it a normal function.

Comment: Like so :
jmp %%ex
< .... >
%%ex:
%endmacro
?

Comment: Something like that. But again, there's not really any point of having `strlen` as part of the macro since its code is identical regardless of the macro argument, and you're `call`ing it anyway, so you're not saving any branches.

Comment: makes sense, would it make sense if i turn strlen itself to an macro?

Comment: it worked so far but it seems to execute pline text2 right before rline comes to the point of interrupt for the user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just forgotten to set the nullbytes for the strlen macro.
couldnt be solved without @Michael

```
section .data
        text1 db "What is your name? ",0,10
        text2 db "Hello, ",0,10
```